# Changing NavigationBar Title of UIImagePickerController in iOS13

Tags: swift, ios13, albumart

In iOS 12 and before I can do below to customized album's first page's title.

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    viewController.title = "customized title!!"
}
```

But it's not working at iOS 13 any more.
Is there anyone could help me for customized that?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I escaped from that.

Comment: Any solution yet? They must have changed something in iOS13. The 'UIImagePickerController' that opens is actually a 'PUPhotoPickerHostViewController' but I can't find any info on this either.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this code :-

```
 func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        viewController.navigationItem.title = "customized title"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following code:

```
func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, willShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationItem.title = "customized title"
}
```